# pe:documentviewer nameddest attribute doesn't work

Tags: pdf, jsf, primefaces-extensions, document-view

I'am trying to show a pdf in a p:dialog , but i want to open pdf in a spécific destination, there is my code:

```
<p:commandLink     value="test" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()"/>  

 <p:dialog header="Dialog"  widgetVar="dlg" 
  resizable="false"   
  fitViewport="true">                
                <pe:documentViewer height="500" width="800" 
                 nameddest="nature"  
                 name="helpImmo.pdf"/>                
 </p:dialog>
```

So the pdf is opened but in the first page

NB:when i use the page attribute it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute `nameddest` of `pe:documentViewer` can be used to open PDF in specific [named destination](http://www.reality-tech.com/url-to-a-location-inside-a-pdf/) which is technically different then [bookmark](https://acrobatusers.com/tutorials/how-to-create-structured-bookmarks).

**To test if your code and project libraries work correctly**, download this [pdf example](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/pd/mydocument-1524150305.pdf#nameddest=Chapter3), include it into your project and in `pe:documentViewer` and set, for example, nameddest="Chapter3".

I've tested it with PF 6.1 and PF-extensions 6.1. It works OK on my side and opens requested named destination.

**So make sure that**

- your PDF actually **has** named destination 'nature' created,
- your version of PF-extensions does not have some known issue related to opening named destinations.

Also you can programmatically add named destinations to your PDF with iText java library as described in this [example](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/actions-and-annotations/named-destinations).

Comment: thanks for the answer but it steel doesn't work, i'am using primefaces 6.1 primefaces-extention 6.1.1.

Comment: Even with PDF example I provided in the answer?

Comment: your version of PF-extensions does not have some known issue related to opening named destinations. can you explain please

Comment: I wrote that in case that you didnt use PF-extensions 6.1.1. But since you are using ver 6.1.1 I am sure that you can disregard that: in my tests I used the same version and it worked fine with PDF example I provided.